# python join two lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, cursor

I have two lists of dictionaires cursor1 and cursor2

```
cursor1=conn.cursor(DictCursor)
query1= "SELECT orderid, create_time FROM order_viw_sgd_00000001 " 
rows=cursor1.execute(query1)

cursor2=conn.cursor(DictCursor)
query2= "SELECT orderid, total_price FROM order_viw_sgd_00000001 " 
rows=cursor2.execute(query2)
```

For example:

cursor 1=[{orderid:001,create_time:10251200},{orderid:002,create_time:10232032}]

cursor 2=[{orderid:002,total price:300},{orderid:003,total price:400}]

expected outcome:[{orderid:001,create_time:10251200,total price:300}]

How do I inner join each dictionary in cursor1 with the corresponding dictionary in cursor2 with common key(orderid)?

I know we can use "join" in the SQL query command, but running time is too long, not efficient. Is there any python-way of doing this?

Comment: The Python running time is not going to be *any better*. You'd have to produce an index, in Python, of `orderid` values in the first set of rows, then use that index to 'join' the two sets of rows. That is exactly what your database does, only it already has that index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double for loop:

```
cursor_1=[
    {'orderid':'001', 'create_time':10251200},
    {'orderid': '002', 'create_time':10232032}
]

cursor_2=[
    {'orderid':'002','total_price':300},
    {'orderid':'003','total_price':'400'}
]

for x, dict1 in enumerate(cursor_1):
    for y, dict2 in enumerate(cursor_2):
        if dict1['orderid'] == dict2['orderid']:
            cursor_1[x].update(dict2)
            del cursor_2[y]
            break
    else:
        ## (for ... else) : If for loop finished normally (without break).
        cursor_1.append(dict2)

print (cursor_1)
```